# Scrollpane table of images

Tags: java, android, libgdx, scene2d, scrollpane

I'm trying to make an Instagram alike gallery function in my app. I now, want to implement a Scroll function. The table with images takes up the full width of the screen, so scrolling should only be up/down. 
This is what I've made so far:

```
table = new Table();
    table.setBounds(0,0,1100,1400);
    table.add(add_button).size(700,250).colspan(3).center().padBottom(50);
    table.row();
    table.add(handler.get(0).getImage()).size(360,360).padRight(3);
    table.add(handler.get(1).getImage()).size(360, 360).padRight(3);
    table.add(handler.get(2).getImage()).size(360,360).row();
    table.add(handler.get(3).getImage()).size(360, 360).padRight(3);
    table.add(handler.get(4).getImage()).size(360, 360).padRight(3);
    table.add(handler.get(5).getImage()).size(360,360).row();
    table.add(handler.get(6).getImage()).size(360,360).padRight(3);
    table.add(handler.get(7).getImage()).size(360, 360).padRight(3);
    table.add(handler.get(8).getImage()).size(360,360).row();
    table.add(handler.get(9).getImage()).size(360, 360).padRight(3);
    table.add(handler.get(10).getImage()).size(360, 360).padRight(3);
    table.add(handler.get(11).getImage()).size(360,360);

    scroll = new ScrollPane(table, uiSkin);
    scroll.setSmoothScrolling(true);

    table.debug();
    uiStage.addActor(table);
    uiStage.addActor(scroll);
```

Well first of all, the table is movable in horizontal. It doesn't stay fit against the sides. Second, the images and the "add_button" stop showing up when I use a ScrollPane. They show up without trouble if I don't use a ScrollPane. So I fear I've implemented it wrong, from the ground up somehow.

Anyone have an idea on this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all to block *horizontal move* you should use [Scroll Pane](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ScrollPane.html) class method named [setScrollingDisabled](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ScrollPane.html#setScrollingDisabled-boolean-boolean-)

```
    ScrollPane scroller;

    ...

    scroller.setScrollingDisabled(true, false);
```

Secondly you need to define scroll pane's size

```
    scroller.setSize(width, height);
```

You can also set position

```
    scroller.setPosition(x, y);
```

Comment: That got it going a bit further! No more scrolling to the sides. But there's still a big dark grey cover over the images. But when I scroll I can see the images laying underneath. I set the scroller to the same size as the table.

Comment: Make sure you do not filling the actor with any black graphics also that the scroll bars are properly set

Comment: Hm, it would be in the JSON I would have to check that I suppose?